# How to save a video chosen from camera roll to an app?

Tags: ios, swift, video, sandbox

I am using https://github.com/deepakraj27/Attachment-Handler-Swift/blob/master/AttachmentHandler.swift to choose photos and videos. I can select a video, even have it show up in my little avplayerlayer, but I can't save it. I can save the URL to core data, but when I try to use it again, I get all kinds of errors ranging from sandbox entitlements to invalid parameters and null arrays.

I've tried saving the URL handed to me to core data, then simply loading the video from it. I get an error about no read access to parent directory.

I've tried taking the contents of the URL using NSData(contentsOF: videoURL) and putting them into the documents folder, then saving THAT url to core data and trying to load the video but I get the same error on load. The save seems to happen without complaint (although I guess I can't PROVE the file is actually saved since I can't load it).

I've got this function to save a video at a URL:

```
func saveVideoToFolder(folderName:String, fileName:String, videoURL:URL) -> URL?{
        let videoFilename = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName + ".MOV"

        print("video file name:\(videoFilename)")

        var videoDataToSave:NSData
        do{
            try videoDataToSave = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL)
            let videoPath:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoFilename)
            videoDataToSave.write(toFile: videoFilename, atomically: false)
            return videoPath
        }catch {
            print("error moving video to folder.")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

this function to play a video at a url:

```
func applyChosenVideo(videoURL:URL){
        self.videoURL = videoURL
        self.exerciseVideoView.isHidden = false
        self.exerciseImageView.isHidden = true

        // Create an AVPlayer, passing it url
        self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

        // Create a new AVPlayerLayer and pass it a reference to the player.
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.exerciseVideoView.bounds
        self.exerciseVideoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }
```

this code when loading:

```
print("video at:\(thisVideo!.videoAddress!)")
applyChosenVideo(videoURL: thisVideo!.videoAddress!)
```

And the document in the repo above to let the user choose the video. Again, choosing it works fine, it'll show up. I just can't seem to save IT or a reference to it.

I'm expecting a string or URL to the video with a given name that when put into my applyChosenVideo function will result in that video being displayed.

When choosing a video:

```
Something went wrong in  image
videourl:  file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/C1E3CF44-0C0C-4DF9-91B6-0617FB78E7BD/tmp/trim.D8376964-FDA4-4956-AF0F-CF7607ECACDB.MOV
File size before compression: 0.0 mb
2019-08-10 13:37:22.552847-0700 MYAPP[2154:628400] [] [13:37:22.553] fsbxpc_obtainSandboxRegistrationForPath signalled err=-17509 (kFigSandboxError_NoReadAccessOfParentDirectory) (No read access to parent directory) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Prototypes/Player/ClientServer/FigSandboxSupport.c:421
2019-08-10 13:37:22.564732-0700 MYAPP[2154:631708] [] [13:37:22.565] fsbxpc_obtainSandboxRegistrationForPath signalled err=-17509 (kFigSandboxError_NoReadAccessOfParentDirectory) (No read access to parent directory) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Prototypes/Player/ClientServer/FigSandboxSupport.c:421
2019-08-10 13:37:22.572325-0700 MYAPP[2154:631708] [] [13:37:22.572] FigCFWeakReferenceTableRemoveValue signalled err=-12065 (kFigCFWeakReferenceTableError_ParamErr) (key is 0) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFWeakReferenceTable.c:271
2019-08-10 13:37:22.574308-0700 MYAPP[2154:631708] [] [13:37:22.574] FigCFWeakReferenceTableRemoveValue signalled err=-12065 (kFigCFWeakReferenceTableError_ParamErr) (key is 0) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFWeakReferenceTable.c:271
File size after compression: 0.0 mb
2019-08-10 13:37:22.667791-0700 MYAPP[2154:632054] [] [13:37:22.668] figCFArrayGetNumberAtIndex signalled err=-12990 (kFigCFUtilitiesError_InvalidParameter) (NULL array) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFUtilities.c:847
2019-08-10 13:37:22.668991-0700 MYAPP[2154:632056] [] [13:37:22.669] figCFArrayGetNumberAtIndex signalled err=-12990 (kFigCFUtilitiesError_InvalidParameter) (NULL array) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFUtilities.c:847
```

and when saving: no errors.

When loading:

```
video at: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F13630C5-E0C6-4430-8A22-367366E79107/Documents/MYFOLDERNAME/1DB3768A-AA52-4743-BD61-2B2934B8FE78.MOV
2019-08-10 13:38:24.292073-0700 MYAPP[2154:628400] [] [13:38:24.292] fsbxpc_obtainSandboxRegistrationForPath signalled err=-17509 (kFigSandboxError_NoReadAccessOfParentDirectory) (No read access to parent directory) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Prototypes/Player/ClientServer/FigSandboxSupport.c:421
2019-08-10 13:38:24.293265-0700 MYAPP[2154:628400] [] [13:38:24.293] fsbxpc_obtainSandboxRegistrationForPath signalled err=-17508 (kFigSandboxError_URLDoesNotExist) (Could not obtain realpath for specified URL) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Prototypes/Player/ClientServer/FigSandboxSupport.c:438
2019-08-10 13:38:24.328018-0700 MYAPP[2154:632335] [] [13:38:24.328] figCFArrayGetNumberAtIndex signalled err=-12990 (kFigCFUtilitiesError_InvalidParameter) (NULL array) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFUtilities.c:847
```

EDIT: 
I'm now able to save the video to camera roll, and to the documents directory. And I'm able to visually verify (using finder) and verify using fileExists() that the app can find the file. But when I try to load it I get this error:

```
2019-08-10 16:13:34.954798-0700 MYAPP[2415:722027] [] [16:13:34.955] figCFArrayGetNumberAtIndex signalled err=-12990 (kFigCFUtilitiesError_InvalidParameter) (NULL array) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFUtilities.c:847
2019-08-10 16:13:34.955375-0700 MYAPP[2415:722026] [] [16:13:34.955] figCFArrayGetNumberAtIndex signalled err=-12990 (kFigCFUtilitiesError_InvalidParameter) (NULL array) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2501.7.1.1/Sources/Utilities/FigCFUtilities.c:847
```

Comment: Is this on iOS 13 beta?  I am finding that I'm having some problems with  AVURLAssetGenerator on iOS 13 betas,  I get FigCFXXX errors  when trying to access  CGImages from the  video. The EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework appears responsible.